# gridview stop selecting when adding button on its layout

Tags: android

below is my gridview layout which work fine without button when i add buttonon its layout its stop selecting clickany image in gridview nothing effect why/?? is there any restriction for gridview to not adding button on its layout??? this is my screen shot  imgur.com/jvGzpRP

```
        I'm changing from this:

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title2"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000" />

  </LinearLayout>

      To this:

  <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />
 </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="0.5"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/ButtonSendFeedback"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/roundshapebtn"
    android:text="Order Now"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="15pt" />
 </LinearLayout>







                    gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview3);
        cla = new CategoryListAdapter5(ProductList.this);
                    gridview.setAdapter(cla);




            public class CategoryListAdapter5 extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;


private AQuery androidAQuery;


public CategoryListAdapter5(Activity act) {
    this.activity = act;
//  imageLoader = new ImageLoader(act);
}

public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ProductList.Category_ID.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder;
    androidAQuery = new AQuery(getcontext());
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewitem3, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    holder.txtText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title2);
    holder.txtText3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title3);
    holder.imgThumb = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image2);

//  holder.txtText.setText(ProductList.Category_name.get(position));
    holder.txtText.setText(Html.fromHtml(ProductList.Category_name.get(position)));
    holder.txtText3.setText(Html.fromHtml(ProductList.Category_price.get(position)));

     androidAQuery.id(holder.imgThumb).image(ProductList.Category_image.get(position), true,  
     true);

    return convertView;
}
private Activity getcontext() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtText;
    TextView txtText3;
    ImageView imgThumb;
}

   }
```

Comment: where is your grid view dear... u didnt use grid view anywhere in this

Comment: what u want to do just paste your screen pic here

Comment: k if possible then u paste your screen here

Comment: You have to set focusable false to gridview.

Comment: check my code now without button gridview focusable change is color orange and wen click go new activity but when adding button gridview not show nay effect not selecting not go another scren why??

Comment: plz add my grid view which i give u in answer

Comment: see screen shot http://imgur.com/jvGzpRP

Answer (score 0):

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F2F2F2" >



    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/img_grid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/back_up_layout"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
         />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/back_up_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back_up"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.65"
            android:background="@drawable/selector"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Backup Now (0)"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />




    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i did like this  <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:columnWidth="80dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="1"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >   stil not working

Comment: problem is on button i guess when i remove button layout then gridview working fine

Comment: can u give me a screen shot which u want to make then only i give u tips

Comment: my screen looklike this www.imgur.com/jvGzpRP   whren adding button gridview not work

Comment: todays best image and browser both button so u want to add that button dear

Comment: now chk my full code i edit my answer and just add one exrta layout for grid view child

Comment: it will help u dear :)

Comment: and how i declair both gridview and listview in maina ctivity? which adapter i load in main gridview or listview?

Comment: ok delete that list view dear it will not 4 u it is my older code so by mistake it paste remove only list view

Comment: u show two buttons there what what things i remove? plz edit ur xml code again

Comment: now chk i think now u understand and accept and like my answer i hope if u like

Comment: suppose i have 9 images in gridview then this button will show with every image???